# scala string, raw string

Tags: string, scala, replace

Is it possible to do:

```
"hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("65", "$")
```

Current result is

```
 scala> "hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars", "$")
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
 ....
```

The expected result in scala 2.10:

```
 hello, I have 65 $
```

Problem is with symbol `$`, I need to process it as string not regexp. I tried to put it into `"""`, or `raw""` but nothing helped

Answer (score 6):

You can either double escape the dollar sign:

```
"hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars", "\\$")
```

Or use Scala triple quotes and single escape.

```
"hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars", """\$""")
```

Either way to you need end up with a String literal equal to "\$" to escape the dollar with a backslash.

**EDIT**

I'm not sure that you want "65 $" - isn't "$65" a better format? For this you need a capture group and a backreference

```
"hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("""(\d++)\s++dollars""","""\$$1""");
```

Output:

```
res3: java.lang.String = hello, I have $65
```

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to escape dollar character because right now it is treated as a part of regex [(end-of-the-string sign)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/bounds.html):

```
"hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("65", "\\$")
res0: String = hello, I have $ dollars
```

It is much more likely you wanted to replace "dollars" word:

```
scala> "hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars", "\\$")
res1: String = hello, I have 65 $
```