# scala, string variable processed as string not regexp

Tags: string, scala, replace

Is it seamlessly possible to do?

```
 scala> val p = "$"
 scala> "hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars", p)
```

Current result is

```
 java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 1
 ....
```

The expected result in scala 2.10:

```
 hello, I have 65 $
```

Problem is with variable `p` which stores symbol `$`, I need to process it as a string not regexp.

**Note:** *I can't modify (e.g. replace all non-letter symbols) the p variable (only standard functions, e.g. .toString)*

**Note2:** The given example is rather toy-example. I'd appreciate a more general solution. I.e. variable `p` can contain any type of content (symbols, numbers, text,...), therefore replacing "$" for "\\$" doesn.t make much sense

(this is improved version of similar problem: [scala string, raw string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15898667/1408096) )

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12115187/replace-with

Comment: @om-nom-nom yes, I read it already, but there is replacement... Doesn't exist some method which would do the task without guessing what variable p can or can not contain in order not to get error?

Comment: @Jesper this is vary different question see note2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Regex.quote` for patterns and `quoteReplacement` for replacement strings.  (These just call into `Pattern`.)

```
scala> import util.matching._
import util.matching._

scala> "hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars", Regex quoteReplacement p)
res7: String = hello, I have 65 $

scala> "dollars".r replaceFirstIn ("hello, I have 65 dollars", Regex quoteReplacement p)
res8: String = hello, I have 65 $

scala> "hello, I have 65 dollars".replaceAllLiterally("dollars", p) // quotes both
res9: String = hello, I have 65 $
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the dollar sign literal, because [Java uses it in its implementation of regular expressions as a group reference](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/255-Issues-with-Dollar-Signs-And-Java-s-Matcher-AppendReplacement-Method.htm).

You noted that you can't modify the string literal in the p variable, so you need to resort to replacing the dollar sign and other special characters like [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29):

```
Pattern.quote(p);
```

Comment: isn't there some other method how to do it? If not, what symbols do I have to replace? I'm aware of  $ and \ -anything else? Variable p can contain everything(text, symbols, numbers,..) therefore I need to get rid of all "special characters"

Comment: Oh, I understood your question the wrong way. I thought you were just concerned with the dollar symbol. Updated my answer.

Comment: I wanted to put simple example - probably I'll edit it. Thanks for answer anyway

Comment: quote is interesting point, but I'll wait if something else will appear

Comment: I've tried your proposal, but it doesn't work: "i have 65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars", Pattern.quote("$")) . gives Illegal group reference error

Answer (score 1):

The problem is replaceFirst() uses regular expressions so:

```
"65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars","$0") // compiles
"65 dollars".replaceFirst("dollars","$")  // throws "StringIndexOutOfBoundsException"
```

If,

```
val dollars = "$"
```

You could escape the $ symbol,

```
"65 dollars".replaceFirst( "dollars", if(dollars == "$") "\\$" else dollars )
```

or use string interpolation,

```
s"65 $dollars"
```

or go old school string manipulation,

```
val t = "65 dollars".split("dollars"); if(t.size>1) t.mkString(dollars) else t(0) + dollars
```

or with a map,

```
val ff = "dollars"
val r1 = "$"
"65 dollars, 3 dollars, 50 dollars".split(ff).zipWithIndex.map{case (t,0) => t+r1; case (t,_) => t+ff}.mkString
```

Comment: pls see my note2, i'm looking for some general solution, not just for $. That means I'm not willing to replace all possible escape and special characters ($,\,&,@, and who knows what else) but to treat the variable p like string instead of regexp

Comment: That's why I provided multiple solutions. You might try string interpolation.  I upvoted your question because the $ symbol can be a "gotcha" unexpected error in regex.

Comment: thanks Keith, but still it is not the expected answer. e.g. if your variable dollars contains "\ " it will throw an error. Yes, you solved $ issue, but there can be similar problems with other symbols e.g. "\". As you stated replaceFirst takes its arugument as regexp - is it possible to change this "feature" into accepting string instead regexp. Or, use other "replaceFirst" function which would do the job?

Comment: I am not aware of a function that will parse a string to sanitize it for regex string replacements.  If you don't use regex you still need do something about the lone backslash "\", as you discovered.

Incidentally, replace() doesn't use regular expressions even though replaceFirst() does.

Comment: yes, replace and replaceAllLitarally works as needed. The only problem is that they replace all occurrences instead of just first one which I need.  Thanks Keith!

Comment: Added an example to my answer that replaces the first string found with a map :)